# Boost converter: using smaller inductance than "typical" application?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I need to boost `3.3V` all the way up to `12.0V`.

Current requirements are rather small, I only need to power an [SSD1309](https://www.hpinfotech.ro/SSD1309.pdf) OLED driver (from pg7):

> Common maximum sink current: **40mA**

Almost all of the available high-quality boost converters are providing way more current than this, so I decided to use the smallest converter I can get: [MP3438](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3793541.pdf):

> The MP3438 is a highly integrated boost
> converter with a 1.2MHz fixed frequency and a
> wide input voltage (VIN) range. The MP3438
> starts up from a VIN as low as 2.7V, and can
> support up to a 2A switching current limit with
> integrated, low RDS(ON) power MOSFETs.

This is their recommended typical application converting 3.3V to 12V:
[image]

There is a section on pg16 "Selecting the Inductor":

> An inductor is required to transfer the energy
> between the input source and the output
> capacitors. A larger-value inductor results in
> less ripple current and a lower peak inductor
> current, which reduces the stress on the power
> MOSFET. However, a larger-value inductor is
> physically larger, has a higher series resistance,
> and has a lower saturation current.
> For most designs, the inductance can be
> estimated with Equation (6):
>
> `L = Vin*(Vout-Vin)/(Fsw*Vout*dIl)`
>
> Where `dIl` is the inductor ripple current.
>
> Choose the inductor ripple current to be
> approximately 20% to 50% of the maximum
> inductor average current.

Question: what is "the maximum inductor average current"? Is it the **40mA**? Or RMS Current (Irms) which is **4.4A** for the recommended inductor?

Calculating the above formula with the recommended 3.3uH inductor:

```
dIL = Vin*(Vout-Vin)/(Fsw*Vout*L)
dIL = 3.3*(12-3.3)/(1200000*12*3.3/1000000)
dIL = 0.60417
```

This means ripple is **604mA**?

Comment: please add the image of led driver and whole lcd module or ref link for similar one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Question: what is "the maximum inductor average current"?*

It is the average inductor current when the current loading on the 12 volt output is greatest. Maybe the boost calculator from [my basic website](http://stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html) might help a tad: -

[image]

I've set the load resistance to 300 Ω to match the 40 mA load current stated in the question.

So, it's running in DCM (discontinuous conduction mode) and, the average inductor current is 145 mA as expected for an ideal circuit. The calculator tells you that the ripple current is 419 mA p-p. The reason why the ripple current value disagrees with the data sheet guidance is because the data sheet assumed the chip would be used in CCM mode.

There's always a more ripply current in DCM because of the inductor current depleting to zero.

<sub>The calculator is for an ideal circuit; there will be switching losses, diode volt drops and inductor resistance losses.</sub>

Comment: I'm a little bit confused here. 1.) Running in DCM due to low load? Is it the only reason of running in DCM? 2.) "The reason why the ripple current value disagrees with the data sheet guidance is because the data sheet assumed the chip would be used in CCM mode. There's always more ripple current in DCM." - completely lost: this means Ir(DCM)>Ir(CCM), right? But your site gave **419mA DCM**, while datasheet formula gave **604mA (CCM** as per your assumption?)?

Comment: @Daniel formula 6 is when in CCM and, CCM means a high load current. CCM cannot be sustained at anything like 40 mA load current. Your circuit will run in DCM and you can't use formula 6.

Comment: It looks to me like the 604 mA value is the peak current at the border between CCM and DCM and, that implies an output current of about 83 mA and not 40 mA. And, that ripple current will remain at 604 mA in CCM for greater load currents. Not sure if you understand DCM and CCM?

Comment: 604mA is the result of the Foruma6 (which is meant for CCM as per your comment). I think I do understand DCM and CCM (based on your site, thx). What I need to know if I can safely change the 3.3uH inductor to a much smaller (below 1uH) due to low power requirement or not. IF I change the inductor, Formula6 might become valid (CCM), resulting huge (above 1A) ripple. Then what does this datasheet sentence mean: **"Choose the inductor ripple current to be approximately 20% to 50% of the maximum inductor average current."** ?

Comment: (1) If you lower the inductance it runs deeper into DCM i.e. there's even less chance it runs in CCM. Use the tool I linked and see. I'm not after traffic; I built the tool to supplement my answers on this site. (2) The sentence is a statement about running in CCM; it's inapplicable to DCM.

Comment: Thx your site is very useful indeed. Just one thing I don't understand. Datasheet says: "A larger-value inductor results in less ripple current and a lower peak inductor current". Which one is ripple current in your site?

Comment: @Daniel I don't explicitly mention ripple current on my site because the image of the waveforms in the calculator show the current waveforms and, the numbers alongside allow you to easily calculate ripple current.

Comment: So, just to be clear, in the example in my answer, ripple current is always \$I_{PEAK}-I_{MIN}\$  measured in amps peak-to-peak @Daniel

Comment: @Andyaka FYI the transistor in your diagram is backwards (P-ch). Curious what your thoughts are on compensation; ordinarily I would assume the calculation should use the device's nominal current range, but this device specifies "Adaptive Constant-Off-Time" whatever that means (but not much apparently, as Vcomp is shown directly compared to low side current?).

Comment: @TimWilliams you are the first to spot that foul anomaly. Thanks for that. I don't know what I was thinking. I'll have to alter my website as well hehe. Regards compensation I haven't looked into the device in the question.

Comment: Website and picture MOSFET fixed now @TimWilliams Many, many thanks for that. I've probably looked at it over a hundred times and not seen that error.

Comment: @Andyaka Just one of those boners, you look at it a hundred times and never catch it... it happens. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

"the maximum inductor average current" should be the output current (+\$I_{R1}\$) *divided by the fraction of time inductor current flows in the direction of the output*. Display current may be 128*320 μA, about 40 mA.
I'd assume current limiting to be dissipative and aim for a voltage low in the range of 7-16 V.
For 12(8) V, 40 mA the average current should not be much higher than \$\frac{12(8)}{3.3}\times 40 mA\$: 145(97) mA.

The computation of the ripple current looks correct, note how it is about 30 % of the MP3438's rated current.

With the current as low as this, it may be hard to find an inductor that allows operation in *continuous conduction mode* (CCM).
This would need a *greater* inductance than *typical application*, which may make it bigger in spite of not needing to be rated for 2 A.
Dis-continuous operation (DCM) shouldn't hurt much, but makes eye-balling \$I_{RMS}\$ and \$I_{peak}\$ harder: simulate!

Comment: I wish to know which value's 20-50% shall be the inductor ripple current. Shall it be 20-50% of MP3438's rated output of **2A**? Or shall it be 20-50% of the inductor's current **4.4A**?

Comment: "would need a greater inductance": how much greater exactly?

Comment: My take is inductor's current. *Not* rated maximum, but average in application/design. Less than 20 % would be well into the region of *diminishing returns*. I think 50 % *as a limit* arbitrary. 100% would be DCM. For low losses at low currents, DCM is fine, but watch the frequency go down and requirements for the output capacitor/filter go up with off-time.

Comment: Minimal inductance for CCM: just set ripple current to twice average (145 mA) and solve. "Proportional" *within CCM*, but, as [Andy aka commented](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666009/boost-converter-using-smaller-inductance-than-typical-application/666015#comment1772898_666021), this formula no longer applies in DCM.